# $im(P) ⊆ ker(P − I)$ iff $P^2 (x) = P(x)$ for all $x ∈ V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Let $P : V → V$ be a linear map. Show that $im(P) ⊆ ker(P − I)$ iff $P^2(x) = P(x) $ for all $x ∈ V$.

I need to write a proof for this and I'm really struggling. So here's what I got so far:

$im(P)⊆V$ and $ker(P)⊆V$. So since $V$ is vector space, by closure, $ker (P)+im (P)⊆V $.

It's an iff statement, so I know I need to prove it in both directions.

First Direction: $im(P) ⊆ ker(P − I)$ implies $P^2(x) = P(x) $ for all $x ∈ V$.

Suppose $m∈im(P)$, so $m∈ker(P − I)$. So, $m∈V$.  And now I'm stuck.

Second Direction: I think I start with $P^2 = P$.
So, $(P-I)∘P = P∘P -I∘P = P∘P-P = P∘P - (P∘P) = 0$ So I now have the kernel. I'm stuck here and fairly confused after that.

I'm having a hard time visualizing and putting together a proper proof. I understand the statement given, but I don't get what the proof is suppose to look like. Could someone please show me how the proof works?

Comment: The square there is with respect to composition. $P^2 (x) = (P \circ P) (x) = P(P(x))$. Hint: linear operators can be added and composed (as if we were adding and multiplicating values). Show for instance that composition is distributive: $T \circ (P + K) = T \circ P + T \circ K$. Note that $P = T$ means $P(x) = T(x)$ for every vector $x$. This will help you to prove both directions.

Comment: @GabrielC.Barbosa how do I incorporate that? I understand composition, but I'm not really sure how to introduce it into my proof

Comment: If $P^2 = P$, what can you tell about $(P - I) \circ P$?

Comment: @GabrielC.Barbosa $(P-I)∘P = P∘P - I∘P$ ?

Comment: $I$ is the identity in composition, $I \circ P$ = $P \circ I = P$. Try doing some "arithmetic" with the operators as if they could be added, multiplied (actually composed) and subtracted and you'll see how you get the result.

Comment: @GabrielC.Barbosa So if $P^2 = P$ then $(P-I)∘P = P∘P-P$?

Comment: You have not used $P^2 = P$ yet

Comment: @GabrielC.Barbosa so I get $ (P−I)∘P=P∘P−P = P∘P-P∘P = 0$? And that means that $P^2(x) = P(x)$ gives the kernel? Sorry for keep asking you, I'm just really having a hard time understanding this problem.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Note that $P = T$ iff $P(x) = T(x)$ for every vector $x$, so $T = 0$ means $T(x) = 0$ for every value. You just need to carefully write the details and you'll see it works and shows the image is contained in the kernel. By the way, don't worry about asking, you're still learning.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if $P\times P=P$, then $\text {im}(P)=\text{ker}(P-I)$
For a general proof(you can use this to deal with all things like $f(x)=0$, $V$ equals to the factors' images or kernels)
Assume you have know about number theory, we know (x, x-1)=1, then there are polynomials $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ such that $u(x)*x + v(x)*(x-1)=1$.
Subtitle $X$ with P(just like Cayley–Hamilton theorem did)
$u(P)P+v(P)(P+1)=I$
For any x belong to V, x=u(P)P(x)+v(P)(P-I)(x)
Since P(P-I)v(P)(x)=0 and same to another.
V=ker(P) + ker(P-I), and two kernels with no joint.
Any vector x belong to the joint, then according to  $x=u(P)P(x)+v(P)(P-I)(x), x=0$
Finally, you can prove Im(p)=ker(P-I) and Im(P-I)=ker(P) easily.
PS: I am just new to here and not good at English, sorry for the casual writing and gammar.

Comment: Welcome to MSe...You can put between dollar any math expressionto use latex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really understand how you can prove $ Im(p)=ker(P-I)$ and $Im(P-I)=ker(P)$ using the polynomials. Is there a simpler way to prove it?

Comment: For any vector $x$ belong to $Im(P)$, I denote that as $x=P(y), (P-I)(x)=0$, then $x$ belong to $Ker(P-I)$ In another hand, for any vector $x$ belong to $Ker(P-I), (P-I)(x)=0$, that means $x=P(x)$ which belong to $Im(P)$

Comment: I use the polynomials for something useful and intersting about $f(P)=0$. But a bit off topic. Btw, in some circumstances, $V= Im(P) + Ker(P)$ and two parts are disjoint. (All what I said about disjoint means the joint is 0 vector) At least, it is right for equations $Px=b$, not for derivative transformation when the bases are polynomials $R[x]$